# WSO2 ESB Accessing application/x-www-form-urlencoded Data

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB.

I want to pass application/x-www-form-urlencoded data to the ESB:

```
curl -v -X POST 'http://myhost/myapi/stuff' -d 'myvar=hello' -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

...and then be able to receive each form variable in my ESB API .

To get a given variable, I'm doing this:

```
<resource methods="POST" uri-template="/stuff">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="myvar" expression="//xformValues//myvar/text()"></property>
...
```

Then I'm storing that in an argument:

```
<args>
   <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:myvar"></arg>
</args>
```

Then I'm later trying to stuff it in a payload with $1.

I know that the issue is with the property line:

```
<property name="myvar" expression="//xformValues//myvar/text()"></property>
```

...because if I store a literal value in the  line, it will work.

I do have the messageReceiver configured in the axis.xml:

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
<messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
```

And, I have the messageBuilder configured in the axis.xml file:

```
<messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    class="org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"/>
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer.

The correct xpath should be:

```
<property name="myvar" expression="//mediate//myvar/text()"></property>
```

This appears to be a known issue, mentioned here:

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3303

- Randy

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
`<property name="myvar" expression="//myvar/text()"/>`
```

It works. 
Actually built message looks like

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mediate>
         <myvar>helloaaaa</myvar>
      </mediate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`
```

So your xpath evaluation fails. hope this helps.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Changed the content type in the request  explicitly to 'application/json'.
That worked.

The problems seems to be that without body and without content-type the default www-urlencode is used. According to the specification that generates xformValues.
If the other side does not expect url encoding the content-type should always be set.